# Unable to load gem installed from git source (LoadError: cannot load such file)

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundle

I have create a gem named `registry_client` in a monorepo structure. With the hope that I can use it internally in my `frontend-app`. However, I encountered this error when I try to run it with bundler `bundle exec ruby app.rb`:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- registry_client
```

The Gemfile in `frontend-app`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'registry_client', git: 'https://github.com/.../some_repo.git', branch: 'master', glob: 'registry-client/*.gemspec'
```

I verified the gem is successfully installed after `bundle install` with `bundle list`:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  ...
  * registry_client (0.1.1 f93f5bd)
  ...
```

This the repo structure:

```
├── frontend-app
│   ├── Gemfile
│   ├── Gemfile.lock
│   ├── Rakefile
│   ├── app.rb
│   ├── config
│   ├── config.ru
│   ├── test
│   └── views
└── registry-client
    ├── Gemfile
    ├── lib
    ├── registry_client.gemspec
    └── test
```

app.rb

```
require 'registry_client'

...
```

registry_client.gemspec

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative 'lib/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = 'registry_client'
  spec.summary       = 'Registry client for using Redis as Service Registry.'
  spec.authors       = ['Author']
  spec.version       = RegistryClient::VERSION
  spec.required_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new('>= 2.3.0')

  # Specify which files should be added to the gem when it is released.
  # The `git ls-files -z` loads the files in the RubyGem that have been added into git.
  spec.files = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(__dir__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  end
  spec.bindir        = 'exe'
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ['lib']
end
```

Edit: added gemspec file

Comment: Run `gem environment`, and capture the value for `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`. Then add `/gems` to the installation directory and list its contents using `ls` command. Do you see your gem there?

Comment: @PetrGazarov The gem is missing in the directory, but I believe might be an expected behavior, from the bundler docs: `Note that because RubyGems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in gem list. They will, however, be available after running Bundler.setup.`

Comment: @PetrGazarov This is what shown under `bundle info registry_client`:

```* registry_client (0.1.1 f93f5bd)
 Summary: Registry client for using Redis as Service Registry.
 Path: /Users/julianho/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/service-api-example-impl-f93f5bd49c46/registry-client```

Comment: When you `ls /Users/julianho/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/service-api-example-impl-f93f5bd49c46/registry-client`, do you see `registry_client.gemspec`?

Comment: Yes. `total 24
drwxr-xr-x   7 julianho  staff   224B Mar 22 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 julianho  staff   320B Mar 22 16:13 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 julianho  staff   115B Mar 22 16:13 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 julianho  staff   270B Mar 22 16:13 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x   6 julianho  staff   192B Mar 22 16:13 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 julianho  staff   832B Mar 22 16:13 registry_client.gemspec
drwxr-xr-x   3 julianho  staff    96B Mar 22 16:13 test`

Comment: What files do you have inside `registry-client/lib`?

Comment: It is just a few files containing the client, `client.rb config.rb version.rb`. I am starting wonder if this is the right way of using internal libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `require` method looks through the directories in the `$LOAD_PATH` and tries to find a file with the name that matches the argument `registry_client`. The `spec.required_paths` attribute in the gemspec specifies:

> Paths in the gem to add to $LOAD_PATH when this gem is activated. The default value is "lib"

Therefore, your `lib` directory must have a file named `registry_client` (in your case, it will have `.rb` extension).
More on this here: https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#loading-code